# RxJava2 database and retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I've two user repository implementation one from local database and other from network using retrofit I am using RxJava2 and MVP

```
override fun loaduserById(id: String): Single<User> {
    return networkService.user(id)
}

override fun loaduserById(id: String): Single<User> {
    return userDao().getUserByID(id)
}
```

I want to get user from database as well as from network parallel

of course database result will be fetched before network result, if the data is in DB

Flow

```
Activity-> Presenter-> Fetch from DB and Network parallel-> 2 conditions 

1. - > Data is in DB -> then show data-> after some time I get data from network also -> update the db with data -> show updated data

2. - > Data not in DB -> Got data from network -> show updated data-> update the db with data
```

How can use RxJava2 to get this flow I've very little experience in RxJava2 operators.

Comment: https://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/.

Comment: @Raghunandan looks very useful.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks I got it. your article gave me useful hints https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/chaining-multiple-sources-with-rxjava-20eb6850e5d9

Comment: glad you found it useful. its not my article the article is from dan lew. so credit to him